# How to effectively and correctly read input from a file in c++?

Tags: c++, input, ifstream

I have a program where I need an option to import information about an event into a calendar. When events get exported, each piece of information has its own line, so I use a combination of >> operator (for int types) and getline (for strings).
Is there a better way to do this? So many lines of code just for input read seem a little unorganized and maybe it's also not the safest way of solving this problem. Does anyone suggest any improvements? Also, is it better to close the file afterwards or is it done automatically?

```
bool importFunction(const string &file, const Calendar &cal) {
  ifstream reader;
  reader.open(file);
  string type, description, country, city, street;
  int day, month, year, fHour, fMinute, fSecond, tHour, tMinute, tSecond, 
  number_street;

  if(reader.is_open()){
  getline(reader, type);
  getline(reader, description);
  reader >> day >> month >> year >> fHour >> fMinute >> fSecond >> tHour >> 
  tMinute >> tSecond;
  reader.ignore();//ignore trailing newline
  getline(reader, country);
  getline(reader, city);
  getline(reader, street);
  reader >> number_street;

  if(type=="long") {
  LongEvent event(description, Date(day, month, year), Time(fHour, fMinute, 
  fSecond), Time(tHour, tMinute, tSecond), Location(country, city, street, 
  number_street));

  cal.addEvent(event);
  }
  else if(type=="short") {
  ShortEvent event(description, Date(day, month, year), Time(fHour, fMinute, 
  fSecond), Time(tHour, tMinute, tSecond), Location(country, city, street, 
  number_street));

  cal.addEvent(event); 
  }


  else cout << "FILE WAS NOT OPENED" << endl;


}
```

Comment: Some small improvements might be possible, but if your data format is that complicated, your reader function will have to be that complicated too.

Comment: Do you have any concrete concerns about safety? Otherwise, I don't really see major improvements, to be honest, maybe others do. Every reading operation seems to serve a distinct purpose, so I don't think there's anything you can do. The code is mostly concise -- except maybe for the object constructions at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a class for the set of input data and create a member function that deals with input operations, whether it was from a file or any other source.

This improvement will just make your code more readable, understandable and object oriented programmed.

But as I can see your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can store date/time value as a single value with `time_t` (64-bit integer on new compilers). Convert to and from `time_t` and your `Calendar` structure. The code will not necessarily be shorter, but file size will be smaller since it contains only one value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
#include <fstream>  

int main()
{
    struct tm timeinfo = { 0 };
    timeinfo.tm_year = 2018 - 1900;
    timeinfo.tm_mon = 0;//<- January
    timeinfo.tm_mday = 1;//<- first
    timeinfo.tm_hour = 1;
    timeinfo.tm_min = 1;
    timeinfo.tm_sec = 1;
    time_t rawtime = mktime(&timeinfo);

    std::ofstream fout("file.txt");
    fout << rawtime;
    fout.close();

    std::ifstream fin("file.txt");
    rawtime = 0;
    fin >> rawtime;

    struct tm *readtime = localtime(&rawtime);

    char buf[100];
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c\n", readtime);
    std::cout << buf;

    return 0;
}
```